# Simple application php ajax not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I made a simple application php & ajax and I don't know why it is not working.

My code:

```
<?php

$grId  = $_GET["groupId"];
$limit = $_GET["limit"];

if ($limit <= 0) {
  $limit = 10;
}

$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "root";
$dbname     = "productsdb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql  = "SELECT id, displayName, role, groupId FROM user where groupId = ? limit ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $grId, $limit);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $displayName, $role, $groupId);
$users = array();

while($stmt->fetch()) {
  $user              = new StdClass();
  $user->id          = $id;
  $user->displayName = $displayName;
  $user->role        = $role;
  $user->groupId     = $groupId;
  array_push($users, $user);
}

echo json_encode($users);

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

json-client-get.html:

```
<html>

<head>
  <script src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#students').hide();
      $("#getStudentsButton").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
          dataType: "json",
          type: "GET",
          url: "getStudentsJson.php",
          data: {
            groupId: 1,
            limit: 7
          },
          success: renderTable
        });
      });

      function renderTable(data) {
        var trHTML = '';
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
          trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.id + '</td><td>' + item.displayName + '</td><td>' + item.role + '</td> <td> ' + item.groupId + ' </td></tr>';
        });

        $('#students').append(trHTML);
        $('#students').show();
      }

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  Lista studentilor din grupul 1:
  <div id="maindiv">
    <table id="students" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Role</th>
        <th>GroupId</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <input id="getStudentsButton" type="button" value="Load students" />
</body>
</html>
```

I craete in phpmyadmin a new database productsdb with the table user and a single value inserted.

When I run localhost/folder/json-client-get.html and press the button Load student nothing is happening.

EDIT(picture with my db but I don't know why the photo is not working)

[image: screenshot with my db]

Comment: it is going into renderTable() function after success?? have you checked by alert in this function?

Comment: take out this -> `$user = new StdClass();` from your `while` loop

Comment: `console.log(data)` in `readerTable` function.

Comment: You `success: renderTable` line should be success: function(){//renderTable}

Comment: @Hirdesh Vishwdewa nothing changes

Comment: `$stmt->store_result();` you might miss this in your code before `$stmt->bind_result($id, $displayName, $role, $groupId);`

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and there is an issue with SQL which you have:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, displayName, role, groupId FROM user where groupId = ? limit ?";
```

check table structure and ensure which you have these fields

for sure run this query in your phpmyadmin and see result

```
SELECT id, displayName, role, groupId FROM user where groupId = 1 limit 7
```

Comment: It runs successfully in phpmyadmin and it gives me the row with the values..I tried to make a photo to my db but it is not working to put it here

Comment: i checked your code several times and just see error when i change query to invalid sql

Comment: and when correct my sql it work fine

Comment: Use his idea, on how to determine the error. you use firebug, or network in chrome for that.

Comment: change codes of your while to array_push($users, array($id, $displayName,$role, $groupId)); and check again, remove other sections of your while

Comment: Again, not working

Comment: @Majid Abbasi and what did you change in order to work?

Comment: Sorry for spamming you but I am still trying to resolve this and I can't figure out. Can you send exactly all the code that works?

Comment: please send your table structure i will send exact code for you.

Comment: at this time this code work for me when i am changing sql, please attach code of StdClass

Answer (score 0):

This answer will not solve your issue but simply show you how to debug your ajax call. I think you will benefit more from knowing how to solve it than getting it solved.

Take a look at the following ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajaxScript.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'somevar': 'somevalue'
        },
        success: function(result)
        {
            alert('Successfully called');
        },
        error: function(exception)
        {
            alert('Exeption:'+exception);
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: And / Or learn how to use your browsers developer tools.